# data annotation showing the same error even while entering same type of data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, annotations, data-annotations, webapi

[image][![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7m[image]FS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7mFS.png)

Here i tried to use data annotations , i tried to implement Range annotation on salary data type which i declared as a int type but even though i tried to enter data as integer only but still its showing error message (please enter number only) and i have tried executing without data annotations method working successfully but not working with the dataannotation range with this specific type only

HOW CAN  SEARCH AND FIND THE PROBLEM TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regular expression Data Annotation is wrong.
Use this instead

`[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{4,5}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter only numbers ")]`